# java - Explanation on "this" statement

Tags: java

I am new to Java, really confused about the outcome of the following program, could someone please elaborate on swapping scenarios?

Also, could someone give me few examples with regards to `this` keyword?

```
class P {
    int i;

    void test1(P p1, P p2) {

        int i = p1.i;
        p1.i = p2.i;
        p2.i = i;;
    }

    void test2(P p1) {

        int i = this.i;
        this.i = p1.i;
        p1.i = i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P p1 = new P();
        P p2 = new P();
        p1.i = 1;
        p2.i = 2;
        p1.test1(p1, p2);
        System.out.println(p1.i + "," + p2.i);
        p1.test(p2);
        System.out.println(p1.i + "," + p2.i);
    }
}
```

> ```
> //Output
> 2.1
> 1.2
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: In your code `this.<variable>`  - `this` refers to the current object.

`this()` is a constructor of the current class. `super()` refers to the super-class constructor.

Comment: where are you using `this()` by the way? I see `this` but not `this()`?

Comment: Sorry, i meant to say `this` reference and not `this()` method.

Comment: Terminology please. `this` is neither a 'statement' nor a 'method'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`this` is **not** a method.  It is a **keyword**.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)  It always refers to the current object it's being referenced from.  Its usage has different contexts:

- If it's being used in front of a *field* name, it is referencing the name of the field specific to that object.

  Example below.  `fooField` in the constructor would shadow the field, but since we're using `this`, we're referring to the specific `Foo` object's field.

  ```
  public class Foo {
      private String fooField;

      public Foo(String fooField) {
          this.fooField = fooField;
      }
  }
  ```

  Don't use this unless you *have* to.  It can lead to confusing and unnecessarily ambiguous code.
- If it's being used as part of a *constructor* construct, then it calls another constructor within the class.  This is called explicit constructor declaration.  The usage of `this` would have to be the first call in a constructor declaration.

  Example below.  Here I have two different constructors for `Point`, and I can call one without arguments by invoking `this(0, 0, 0)`.

  ```
  public class Point {
      private int x, y, z;

      public Point() {
          this(0, 0, 0);
      }

      public Point(int x, int y, int z) {
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.z = z;
      }
  }
  ```

Now, as to why your program produces that output.

`test1` does some funny things with its variables...you take in two sides, left and right (for disambiguation's sake).

- You assign the callee the value of the left.  // P1.i = 1
- The left side now takes the value of the right. // P1.i = 2
- The right takes the value of the callee. // P2.i = 1

In the above case, the callee and left are the same object.  So, you result in output 2,1.

`test2` is slightly different.  You have only one argument, so it'll be the "argument" (for disambiguation's sake).

- You explicitly reassign the value of the callee to itself.  // P1.i = P1.i == 2
- You assign the argument's value to the callee.  // P1.i = 1
- You assign the callee's value to the argument. // P2.i = 2

Thus, you result in 1,2 for your output.

Answer (score 0):

**`this` is a reference to the *current object***

The most common reason for using the `this` keyword is because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

You can use `this` as a constructor -> `this()`

**`this()` is a reference to another constructor in the same class**

```
public Rectangle() {
    this(0, 0, 0, 0); // calls the constructor below
}

public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
    this(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: `this()` in a constructor refers to the current class's available constructors. So, in a constructor, yes, `this()` is a method.

Comment: `this()` refers to the current object - in a constructor, one can call `this()` to refer to the empty constructor, in much the same way one calls `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void test1(P p1, P p2) {    
        int i = p1.i;
        p1.i = p2.i;
        p2.i = i;;
}
```

This method can be `static` as it is just swapping the values and is not dependent on instance.

```
void test2(P p2) {    
        int i = this.i;
        this.i = p2.i;
        p2.i = i;
}
```

Here `this.i` points to the object on which you have called `test2` method, in your case it is `p1` and you are passing `p2` as argument which also does the same swap operation.

So as both the methods do same thing:

You start with values 1,2 --`After test1()` --> 2,1 -- `After test2()` --> 1,2 where you started from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the following block, what does "int i" and "i" refers to in its relative term. Is there any specific reason.             
    `void test1(P p1, P p2)
    {
    
    int i = p1.i
    p1.i = p2.i
    p2.i = i;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

'this' is a pointer that points to itself.
Sometimes a method needs to refer to the object that invoked it.To allow this, Java defines the 'this' keyword.Moreover 'this' can be used inside any method to refer to current object.

For eg. when we have a method displayName()

```
displayName()
{
 System.out.println("Name: " + name);
}
```

Now we are invoking it with object f1

```
f1.displayName() //compiler converts this thing in displayName(f1)
```

and in displayName() method it collects object f1 like this

```
displayName(this)
{
 System.out.println("Name: " + this.name); //here this.name means its referring to class member variable.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this keyword refers to the current instance of class.
you can also use 'this' to create methods which return your object after each call. This is useful i.e. for classes configurators.

Example of usage:

```
public class SomeCLass {

//some fields

//some constructors

    public SomeClass setWidth(width) {
        this.width = width;
        return this;
    }

    public SomeClass setLength(length) {
        this.length = length;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Execute {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new SomeClass()).setWidth(10).setLength(15);
}
```